# A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a parameter of type 'Key' in a const constructor. Try using a subtype, or removing the keyword 'const'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

class CreateNewAccount extends StatelessWidget {
const CreateNewAccount({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
return Stack(
children: [
const BackgroundImage(image: 'assets/Logo_New.png', key: null,),
Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
body: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: [
SizedBox(
height: size.width * 0.1,
),
Stack(
children: [
Center(
child: ClipOval(
child: BackdropFilter(
filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
child: CircleAvatar(
radius: size.width * 0.14,
backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400]?.withOpacity(
0.4,
),
child: Icon(
FontAwesomeIcons.user,
color: kWhite,
size: size.width * 0.1,
),
),
),
),
),
Positioned(
top: size.height * 0.08,
left: size.width * 0.56,
child: Container(
height: size.width * 0.1,
width: size.width * 0.1,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: kBlue,
shape: BoxShape.circle,
border: Border.all(color: kWhite, width: 2),
),
child: const Icon(
FontAwesomeIcons.arrowUp,
color: kWhite,
),
),
)
],
),
SizedBox(
height: size.width * 0.1,
),
Column(
children: [
const TextInputField(
icon: FontAwesomeIcons.user,
hint: 'User',
inputType: TextInputType.name,
inputAction: TextInputAction.next, key: null,
),
TextInputField(
icon: FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
hint: 'Email',
inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
inputAction: TextInputAction.next, key: null,
),
const PasswordInput(
icon: FontAwesomeIcons.lock,
hint: 'Password',
inputAction: TextInputAction.next, inputType: null, key: null,
),
PasswordInput(
icon: FontAwesomeIcons.lock,
hint: 'Confirm Password',
inputAction: TextInputAction.done, inputType: null, key: null,
),
const SizedBox(
height: 25,
),
const RoundedButton(buttonName: 'Register', key: null,),
const SizedBox(
height: 30,
),
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
const Text(
'Already have an account?',
style: kBodyText,
),
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
},
child: Text(
'Login',
style: kBodyText.copyWith(
color: kBlue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
),
],
),
const SizedBox(
height: 20,
),
],
)
],
),
),
)
],
);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a nullable value in a const constructor, so replace this

```
class CreateNewAccount extends StatelessWidget { const CreateNewAccount({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

with

```
class CreateNewAccount extends StatelessWidget { const CreateNewAccount({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```